# Where/how does pension tax relief for higher rate tax payers get paid once a self-assessment tax claim is completed?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, self-assessment, pension-sipp

If a UK higher rate taxpayer makes payments into a SIPP, and then completes a tax self-assessment form, how will the government return the money? Does it pay it to a person's bank account? Into their pension, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get my tax refunds paid direct into my bank account. They certainly won’t be paid into your pension.

Answer (score 2):

The one time I did it they sent me a cheque. These days you may be able to [claim online](https://www.gov.uk/tax-overpayments-and-underpayments/if-youre-due-a-refund).

> Your P800 will tell you if you can [claim your refund online](https://www.gov.uk/check-income-tax-last-year).

Any payments into your pension you'd have to arrange yourself, keeping in mind your annual contribution limit.